# Class rewrite / extends and constant validity?

Tags: module, extend, undefined-variable

I try to implement a module in which I need to rewrite Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option.

I then add the following file to the module

```
<?php
class Mine_Custoptiontype_Model_Catalog_Product_Option extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option
{
    const OPTION_GROUP_FILESSTATE       = 'filesstate';
    const OPTION_TYPE_FILESSTATE_TYPE   = 'filesstate_type';
    /**
     * Get group name of option by given option type
     *
     * @param string $type
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGroupByType($type = null)
    {
        if (is_null($type)) {
            $type = $this->getType();
        }

        $group = parent::getGroupByType($type);
        if( $group === '' && $type = self::OPTION_TYPE_FILESSTATE_TYPE ){
            $group = self::OPTION_GROUP_FILESSTATE;
        }
        return $group;

    }
    /**
     * Group model factory
     *
     * @param string $type Option type
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option_Group_Abstract
     */
    public function groupFactory($type)
    {
        if( $type === self::OPTION_TYPE_FILESSTATE_TYPE ){
            return Mage::getModel('custoptiontype/catalog_product_option_type_filesstatetype');
        }
        return parent::groupFactory($type);
    }
}
?>
```

and modify my model config.xml file :

```
<models>
  <catalog>
    <rewrite>
      <product_option>Mine_Custoptiontype_Model_Catalog_Product_Option</product_option>
    </rewrite>
  </catalog>
</models>
```

but when I would like to access the OPTION_GROUP_FILESSTATE and OPTION_TYPE_FILESSTATE_TYPE using app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Option.php,

I have got errors saying these 2 constant do not exist…

Help me please !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access constants from a child class using the parent class name.
Those constants don't exist in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option`.
You should be able to access them like this:

```
Mine_Custoptiontype_Model_Catalog_Product_Option::OPTION_GROUP_FILESSTATE
Mine_Custoptiontype_Model_Catalog_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_FILESSTATE_TYPE
```

Comment: @Alexglvr. If this solved your issue, mark the answer as accepted. Let's keep this website healthy.

Comment: Hello how to unregister or registry OPTION_GROUP_FILESSTATE contants

Comment: @MagikVishal. I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: i want like that Mage::register(self::OPTION_GROUP_FILESSTATE, 'newfilesstate');

Comment: This looks kind of out of the scope of this question. Please as an other question and describe what are your trying to achieve. In case you want to change the value of a constant, that's not possible. that's why they are called constants.

Comment: Check comment answer

Comment: i delete my answers please check my code give suggestion class test_demo_Block_Catalog_Product_Price extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price {   
    const CALLED = false ;
    if( !Mage::registry(self::CALLED)) {
      //some code here
      Mage::register(self::CALLED, true);
      // above line code for onetime loop 

  }

}